# CSS class with colon

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the [Topcoat](http://www.topcoat.io) CSS library. You can see the code snippet I'm having problems with [here](http://topcoat.io/topcoat/topcoat-desktop-light.html#large-textinput).

In the style sheet, there is the following to put a red border around an input when invalid:

```css
.topcoat-text-input--large:invalid {
  border: 1px solid #EC514E;
}
```

My HTML content is:

```html
<input type="text" class="topcoat-text-input--large" id="email" placeholder="email" value="<%= model.email %>">
```

How do I set the input to use the CSS for invalid? If I change the class of the input from:

```
topcoat-text-input--large
```

to

```
topcoat-text-input--large:invalid
```

I don't get the red border. How can I use this CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:invalid` pseudo-class is triggered when the `pattern` input attribute is not matched.

In the linked example:

```
<input type="text" class="topcoat-text-input--large" placeholder="text" value="fail" pattern="not-fail">
```

If you type "not-fail" into the box, it will turn blue. If you type anything else, it does not match the `pattern` and is `invalid`.

For more information, see the MDN article on [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).

> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset. Use the title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored. The regular expression language is the same as JavaScript's. The pattern is not surrounded by forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

The [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) part of the selector is not part of the class, but something called a *pseudo class*. In the case of :invalid, it only activates when ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)):

> an `<input>` or `<form>` element whose content fails to validate according to the input's type setting.